# Merge bits from hex value

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have two uint32_t variables.
These have following values -

```
uint32_t a = 0x00002000;
uint32_t b = 0x00c00000;
```

I want these two variable to be merged so they give the result `0000200c`.

If I simply do `a+b`, it does not return the correct result. Could anyone please help?

Edit - I need to put Bit number 31-20 of b to bit number 11-0 of a.

Comment: You need to read more about the bitwise operators, for this case you need the and operator `&`, the shift operators `>>` or `<<` and the or operator `|`.

Comment: What’s the logic for that result? It’s definitely not a concatenation. Maybe a concatenation of `a` with a zero-trimmed version of `b`.

Comment: I got these values by using those operators. I am simply not able to figure out the shifting. I tried shifting by 20 but didnt work.

Comment: What did you mean by concatenation? `00002000c` is not the concatenation of `00002000` and `00c00000`.

Comment: the logic is I need to add the bit number 31-20 of b to bit number 12-0 of a.

Comment: That seems like an odd division, especially since you're skipping 7 bits in the middle. What should the value of those 7 bits be?

Comment: Your desired output is of 36 bits. I think its a typo. (is it?)

Comment: Since this is not concatenation, I edited the text so it does not confuse future readers.

Comment: Thank you.:) much appreciated,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bits 31-20 of `b` can be isolated by doing `(b & 0xFFF00000)`.

Bits 11-0 of `a` can be isolated by doing `(a & 0x00000FFF)`.

Then you need to shift the `b` variable to the right by 20 bits before combining it with `a`. Putting it all together, you get

```
uint32_t answer = ((b & 0xFFF00000) >> 20) | (a & 0x00000FFF);
```